# How can I host website over the internet using Apache2 and Ubuntu Server?

Tags: apache-http-server, ip, website, localhost, ubuntu-server

I'm running Apache2 on Ubuntu Server 15.04. For simplicity, I removed all the routers in between. Presently, my server is directly connected to the internet. All that is there in my home network is one computer.

All I want is this -

I run `curl 127.0.0.1` to access website locally. Or putting in `localhost` in my browser should display my website.

I run `curl ipecho.net/plain | curl` on some other machine to access the same website. Or putting in `http://<my ip addr>` should let me see my website.

But unfortunately, I'm unable to do so.
As of now, I can only access my webpage locally, i.e. by putting in `localhost`. What I can't do is view this website on the internet.
I have tried on different ports`(80, 72, 8090, 44346)`, but in vain. What am I doing wrong? All I want is to access my website over the internet.

Comment: **Update:** A few weeks after posting this question, I came to understand that my internet connection was behind a carrier-grade NAT erected by my ISP that left my server unreachable from the rest of the internet.

Comment: I resolved the issue by switching to IPv6. :D

Answer (score 0):

You stated your server is directly connected to the Internet now. Can you access websites from a browser on that server or [ping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping_(networking_utility)) outside systems successfully? E.g., does `ping google.com` work successfully? Can you ping your server from an external system? If you don't know the external IP address that other systems will need to use to access your server, you can determine that IP address by opening a browser on the server and visiting [WhatIsMyIP.com](http://www.whatismyip.com).

If you have firewall software running on the system, e.g., [iptables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iptables), you will need to configure the firewall software to allow inbound connections to port 80. For iptables, the command `sudo iptables -L` will show you the current firewall rules. You can allow inbound connections to port 80 with `sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT` or you can install the Uncomplicated Firewall (UFW) package to simplify the management of iptables firewall rules with `sudo apt-get install ufw` and then enable it and permit inbound port 80 connections with the following commands:

```
sudo ufw enable
sudo ufw allow 80
```

See [How To Setup a Firewall with UFW on an Ubuntu and Debian Cloud Server](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-a-firewall-with-ufw-on-an-ubuntu-and-debian-cloud-server) for further information on the use of UFW.

If you do have Internet access from the server and access to it from external systems isn't being blocked by firewall software, then perhaps your issue may lie in the configuration of the Apache web server software. Check Apache's `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` configuration file. Look for the following line:

```
Listen 80
```

That line will allow Apache to listen for connections to port 80 on all IP addresses for the system. If, instead, you see `Listen 127.0.0.1 80`, then it is only listening on the [localhost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost) address.

Do you have any section like the following in that `httpd.conf` file or in a virtual host file for your site in `/etc/httpd/conf.d`?

```
<Directory />
  Order Deny,Allow
  Deny from all
  Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Directory>
```

The `Deny from all` statement followed by the `Allow from 127.0.0.1` would only permit access from the localhost address.

Comment: pinging google from my server works. I even opened the firewall at port 80. But even then it doesn't seem to work. Pinging my server from my own server works (using public IP). But unfortunately, pinging my server from an external device didn't work. I don't get the reason.

Comment: Also all the configuration settings in `apache2.conf` file seems  to be fine. It looks like I can't connect to my server from any other external system despite allowing the firewall.

Comment: Moonpoint, Just to make sure the ISP isn't blocking port 80, I changed it to 72. But it still doesn't work. Anybody any ideas?